# Processing: Is there a better way to make a top down camera with P3D Renderer

Tags: java, graphics, processing

I'm making a top-down game where the camera centers the player in the middle of the screen. The code I have works, but I don't understand the eyeXYZ parameters. If I put a number less than 1000000000 like 100 the game will be very glitchy and the angle will no longer be perpendicular (top down).

Is there a better way to make a camera that follow the player from a top-down perspective in Processing? Here's what I have:

```
camera(0.0, 0.0, 1000000000, player.x+300, player.y, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
ortho(-width, width, -height, height);
```

Comment: What axis is up in your scene?

Comment: the z axis is up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first three parameters specify the position of your camera (the eye). Hence, if you want your camera to be over your player, then you should use:

```
camera(player.x, player.y, player.z + cameraHeight ...
```

`cameraHeight` is the distance of the camera over the player. Since you are using an orthographic view, this value doesn't really matter. It is only important for proper depth values (and that depends on the values for znear and zfar, which the Processing documentation isn't very helpful about).

The next three parameters are the position of the focus point. If you want to focus on the player, you should use:

```
... player.x, player.y, player.z ...
```

(I'm not sure what this `+300` is supposed to do).

The last three parameters are the direction that points upwards in the image. The y-axis should be fine.

```
... 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
```

And that's it.

The reason why your super-large z-coordinate of the eye worked is because this basically degenerated the `+300` offset. In comparison to `1000000000`, `300` is practically zero, which is why it looked perpendicular. When you decreased the z-coordinate, the influence of the `300` become stronger and the non-perpendicularity became more obvious.

Comment: 300 is offset for the HUD. HUD is occupying part of the screen.

Comment: Then this offset has to be present in the eye coordinates as well to keep it perpendicular.

Comment: Thank you, this makes a lot of sense now.